# How do I open a view from storyboard in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created a webview inside the `Main.storyboard`.

[image]

Now I would like to programmatically add the URL to this view, and modify its width/height etc, but how do I open this webView source code? When I go to `ViewController.swift` all it gives me is the default

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Xcode (as well as Stackoverflow) does not write code for you . Please read the [WKWebView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview). There is even sample code.

Comment: please go through this tutorials https://www.appcoda.com/tag/wkwebview/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for taking an instance of `WKWebView` from storyboard to swift.
Take an `IBOutlet` of `WKWebView`. Open the `Main.storyboard`, Set the ViewController's custom class. Then open the Assistant editor. Then Take an `IBOutlet` of the `WKWebView` into the swift.

Comment: `UIWebView` is deprecated. The object in the screenshot is `WKWebview`